# Chrome Headless doesn't work with Google Maps 3D or Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I was under the impression that Chrome Headless was a fully featured version of Chrome that could run anything that Chrome Desktop can also run. However, it appears that Chrome Headless is unable to display 3D pages from Google Maps and Google Earth.

Example Google Maps URL:

> https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.6506889,-0.4041839,40a,35y,113.57h,73.36t/data=!3m1!1e3

Google Earth:

> https://earth.google.com/web/@51.6499525,-0.40162489,64.98644774a,251.31324967d,35y,111.968

Here's an example from the terminal:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://earth.google.com/web/@51.6499525,-0.40162489,64.98644774a,251.31324967d,35y,111.96869586h,49.99995375t,0r
```

And an example using puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({width:2880, height:1800});
    await page.goto('https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5516152,0.7010375,66a,35y,170.86h,79.21t/data=!3m1!1e3', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle"});
    await page.screenshot({ path: './example-2d.png' });

    browser.close();
}

run();
```

**What is the expected result?**

I expect the result to render the same way as it does in the Chrome Browser for desktop.

**What happens instead?**

For the google maps link it renders in 2D rather than 3D.

For google earth an error message is given:

> Aw Snap! The new Google Earth isn't supported by your browser yet. Try this link in Chrome instead. If you don't have Chrome installed, download it here.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be? Does something need to be enabled within Chrome in order to properly render maps and earth?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. Since you're using `--disable-gpu`, WebGL won't work. I can get 3D Google Maps to work by removing this flag, but since [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) says that this flag is needed, it might not work everywhere.
2. earth.google.com/web uses [pnacl](/questions/tagged/pnacl), which seems not to be supported under headless.

I was able to get 3D Google Maps to work by omitting `--disable-gpu`, but the screen shot command produced a page that hadn't finished rendering, so I had to use the remote debugger.